# Arrays of Keys and Values from Request.Form in ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to get an array of keys from Request.Form in ASP Classic.  Theoretically I should simply be able to use `Request.Form.Keys` and `Request.Form.Items`, but they simply don't work.  I get:

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'request.form.Keys'

I've tried making functions of my own, but they ultimately fail on the same point -- .Keys fails when running it on a Request.Form dictionary.

What the heck am I doing wrong????

```
Function dictionary_keys( dict )
    Dim i
    ReDim theKeys( dict.Count-1 )
    for i = 0 To dict.Count-1
        theKeys(i) = dict.Keys(i)
    next
    dictionary_keys = theKeys
End Function

Function dictionary_values( dict )
    Dim i
    ReDim theVals( dict.Count-1 )
    for i = 0 To dict.Count-1
        theVals(i) = dict.Keys(i)
    next
    dictionary_values = theVals
End Function
```

^^ Both of those fail at `dict.Keys(i)`

UPDATE: Based on @Lankymart's answer below, this is what I came up with:

```
Function request_keys( req )
    Dim key, result, i
    i = 0
    ReDim result( req.Count-1 )
    For Each key in req
        result(i) = key
        i = i + 1
    Next
    request_keys = result
End Function

Function request_values( req )
    Dim key, result, i
    i = 0
    ReDim result( req.Count-1 )
    For Each key in req
        result(i) = req(key)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    request_values = result
End Function
```

Comment: The `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` are special collections, not `Scripting.Dictionary` objects and don't support the `Keys` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` collections are not `Scripting.Dictionary` objects and as such don't support the `Keys` collection, but it's simple enough to convert them to a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

```vb
Dim dict: Set dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim key

For Each key in Request.Form
  Call dict.Add(key, Request.Form(key))
Next
```